# Why is the runtime of this algorithm O(m+n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I don't understand how the runtime of the following algorithm can be O(m+n).
About the algorithm, it is used to find a common node of two lists (the lengths of both lists can be different).

```
 if (len1 < len2)
  {
      head1 = list2;
      head2 = list1;
      diff = len2 - len1;
  }
```

This should be O(1).

```
for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
      head1 = head1->next;
```

O(n).

```
while(head1 !=  NULL && head2 != NULL)
  {
      if(head1 == head2)
          return head1->data;
      head1= head1->next;
      head2= head2->next;
  }
```

O(n).

In total i get to O(n^2)...

Here full algorithm:

```
struct node* findMergeNode(struct node* list1, struct node* list2)
{
  int len1, len2, diff;
  struct node* head1 = list1;
  struct node* head2 = list2;

  len1 = getlength(head1);
  len2 = getlength(head2);
  diff = len1 - len2;

  if (len1 < len2)
  {
      head1 = list2;
      head2 = list1;
      diff = len2 - len1;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
      head1 = head1->next;

  while(head1 !=  NULL && head2 != NULL)
  {
      if(head1 == head2)
          return head1->data;
      head1= head1->next;
      head2= head2->next;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: "In total i get to O(n^2)" why do you think running an `O(n)` loop **followed by** an `O(n)` loop would be `O(n^2)`? (That's followed by, not *inside*).

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. So as an example, if we got a for loop within a for loop, that would be O(n^2), right?

Comment: @element115 . . . It depends what the limits of the for loops are, but under many circumstances, yes, that would be O(n^2).

Comment: @element115 if your problem is solved, select the answer that helped you most - no need to edit your question... http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Why in this tagged Java? It looks like C to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are doing is iterating the given lists independently from one another.
What is taking the longest here actually is determining the size of the lists. (This alone if `O(n+m)`)

```
struct node* findMergeNode(struct node* list1, struct node* list2)
{
    // Assuming list1 is of size m
    // Assuming list2 is of size n

    int len1, len2, diff;
    struct node* head1 = list1;
    struct node* head2 = list2;

    len1 = getlength(head1); // O(m) - as you need to iterate though it
    len2 = getlength(head2); // O(n) - same here
    diff = len1 - len2;

    // Right now you already reached O(m+n)

    if (len1 < len2) // O(1)
    {
        // this entire block is of constant length, as there are no loops or anything
        head1 = list2;
        head2 = list1;
        diff = len2 - len1;
    }

    // So we are still at O(m+n)

    for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++) // O(abs(m-n)) = O(diff)
        head1 = head1->next;

    // As diff = abs(m-n) which is smaller than m and n, we can 'ignore' this as well
    // So we are - again - still at O(m+n)

    while(head1 !=  NULL && head2 != NULL) // O(n-diff) or O(m-diff) - depending on the previous if-statement
    {
        // all the operations in here are of constant time as well
        // however, as we loop thorugh them, the time is as stated above
        if(head1 == head2)
            return head1->data;
        head1= head1->next;
        head2= head2->next;
    }

    // But here again: n-diff < n+m and m-diff < n+m
    // So we sill keep O(m+n)

    return NULL;
}
```

Hope this could help.